# Set Modal window height based upon browser window size using Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

how to set the max-height for the modal window to be 80% of the current browser window size using bootstrap.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to just use a wrapper. For example you could use code like this:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Your Code Here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    height: 80%;
}
```

So simply you would just put that `#wrapper` around all of your code (of course after the body), and it would make the max height of all of your content 80%.

Comment: I tried this but in this scroll-bar does come, even I used Overflow:auto.

Comment: I am confused, you would or would NOT like the 80% to scroll? If you do not want it to scroll than would you like it hidden?

Comment: I want scroll on modal popup

Comment: I am sorry, I am just still confused :( So you want to scroll ONLY on the popup?

Comment: Even I am sorry for this confusion. I want to set the max-height for the modal window to be 80% of the current browser window size. In case of overflow scroll bar should come.  I used this css #wrapper { height: 80%; overflow: auto }. But this is not working as expected.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I do not know :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do: **restrict dialog height**.

```
.modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Example Snippet

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 0;
}
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #3c7dcf;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.modal-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6598d9;
  border: 0;
}
.modal-title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.modal-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f3f5;
}
.btn {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:active:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.btn-modal {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn-modal:hover,
.btn-modal:focus,
.btn-modal:active {
  height: 75px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #266080;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.btn-primary {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0791DE;
  border: 1px solid #266080;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #266080;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.btn-secondary {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus,
.btn-secondary:active {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #266080;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h1:first-child,
h2:first-child,
h3:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #266080;
}
p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  background: #f1f3f5;
  border-left: 1px solid #d3d9e0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #b5c0cb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ehModal">View Fullscreen Modal</button>
<div id="ehModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ehModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 id="ehModalLabel" class="modal-title">
          Modal Title
        </h1>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>1. Modal Sub-Title</h2>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2>2. Modal Sub-Title</h2>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2>3. Modal Sub-Title</h2>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2>4. Modal Sub-Title</h2>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <h2>5. Modal Sub-Title</h2>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
    unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
    text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
    Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
    dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `max-height: calc(100% - 120px);`
I hope this will help.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/vggwstmg/)